# Jenkins marking a build as UNSTABLE even if all tests are passing

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

Jenkins marking a Build as UNSTABLE even if all tests are passing.

Error message says: Failed to read test report file XML.

```
Failed to read test report file /scratch/jenkins/workspace/ngcmonitor/target/surefire-reports/TEST-myngconnect_server_status.qa3.Test_Existing_Credentials_Check_QA3.xml
org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory     Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:130)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:274)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:230)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:199)
at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:628)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:610)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:306)
at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:227)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:173)
at org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor.buildReportPlugin(DefaultMavenReportExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor.buildMavenReports(DefaultMavenReportExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.getReports(AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.java:235)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getDocumentFactory(SAXReader.java:645)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createContentHandler(SAXReader.java:969)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:449)
... 54 more
Nested exception: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getDocumentFactory(SAXReader.java:645)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createContentHandler(SAXReader.java:969)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:449)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:130)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:274)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:230)
at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:199)
at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:628)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:610)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:306)
at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:227)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:173)
at org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor.buildReportPlugin(DefaultMavenReportExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor.buildMavenReports(DefaultMavenReportExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.getReports(AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.java:235)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please advise

Comment: Check if the contents of this file makes sense: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/ngcmonitor/target/surefire-reports/TEST-myngconnect_server_status.qa3.Test_Existing_Credentials_Check_QA3.xml

Comment: Simson, I checked the XML file and it is not useful to me, is there any way by which we can stop creation of this XML, so that build is not marked as UNSTABLE.

Answer (score 0):

That xml is a JUnit test report, so if you want to prevent Jenkins from parsing it, you should remove the `JUnit performance test report` step from your job, or any other step that relies on these reports generated by the maven surefire plugin.

The exception you are getting is most probably a classpath issue having to do with plugins packing and relying on different versions of the `dom4j` library. [This issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7666) could be the same as yours or related, and may give you a starting point should you want to further investigate the problem.

Comment: I am using "mvn site" to generate tests report.

POM snippet:
`<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
.....
</build>  
<reporting>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>`

is there anything I am missing.

Comment: It's not maven related, it's a Jenkins classpath issue. See if the link I suggested also applies to you, or if you do not want to generate those reports as you replied to Simson, run maven with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`